# How can I make lines wrapped in css, html or js

Tags: web

I'm using Arabic language while designing my website and I want to wrap lines like it displays in Microsoft word (in that there is no line wider/smaller than another)

http://c.top4top.net/p_432s7e8u0.png

Comment: And what is your effort to this problem?At least show your html and css

Answer (score 0):

Without any example of your code, it's hard to say based on your personal situation but you may be looking for the following CSS property:

*word-wrap: break-word*

This should wrap your text in an element where this property is applied.

See the following link from W3Schools.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

If this isn't what you're looking for, post an example of your code and we can try again!! :)

Comment: Sorry for not clearing what I meant by my question.. I just have added a picture to clear my question for the website content itself..

Comment: Hi Alex, I can see the image but it would be helpful to show the HTML/CSS code used in the area so we can see how the markup is constructed and potentially what is causing the problem/what we can do to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure whether you're talking about your actual website content or your IDE / Developer Tool. I'd assume the latter as you're talking about javascript and css (which the user wouldn't see on the page) but hey, here's a reference to how to show users it like that (on a website) anyway

**"how do you change spacing of words to fit the whole line?"**
https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/how-do-you-change-spacing-of-words-to-fit-the-whole-line-248002/

For line wrap, I suggest Googling "line wrap " + the tool you're using

For justify, it's likely not supported in the tool you're using, but you can still throw an attempt at Googling "justify text in " + the tool you're using

> Note: I'd give more information, but your question lacks detail

Comment: Sorry for not clearing what I meant by my question.. I just have added a picture to clear my question for the website content itself..( I tried to use word wrap property but it doesn't wotk for me)

Comment: @Alex I seem to be unable to view the picture, can you post it elsewhere?